# Making a textinput with a predefined value in Kivy Python

Tags: python, widget, kivy, textinput

I'm working with a text input in a Kivy App but I don't know how to do a thing. The fact is I want to do a `textinput` that shows the values you can enter. I know it could be with text='...' but I want the predefined text to be erased when I select the text input. I don't know if Kivy could do this, because I want to show always that the textinput is empty a list with the numbers you can input.The function func is only to save the input of the widget. I don't want to do with kv language, so I've done this way because for the hole app is better:

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
textinput = TextInput(text='You can Input 1,2,3,4',multiline=False)
textinput.bind(on_text_validate=func)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `hint_text`?

Comment: Uouuu it works! Thank you! I have some more issues, I'll try to fix them.

Comment: I've posted the comment as answer so you can accept that and close the question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `hint_text` to specify a placeholder for the `TextInput`